# Merge a cell in excel, depending on it's value

Tags: vba, excel

I want to merge a cell automatically with the one underneath if the cell has a certain `value ("vv")`. 
a solution i found is to check every cell in an array every time a change is made, but thought there would be a possibility to check the value of a `cell` after it `changed`?

So if I enter in a blank cell `"vv"` (without quotes) and I select a different cell I'd like that cell (with vv in it) to merge with the one right under it. 
in my solution with the array it takes a second every time you change a cell, which is not neat if you make a lot of changes. 
Any help?

Comment: What if you have any value in the cell right underneath the cell you are typing? e.g. B2 you are typing `vv`. Then B3 has some other value. Or you don't care about it at all?

Comment: @bonCodigo: Good point. I amended the answer to ask the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code in your worksheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Value = "vv" Then Target.Resize(2).Merge
End Sub
```

In case you want to prevent any content in the cell below, this code will ask you if the cells shall be merged in case any content is found:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Value = "vv" Then 
        If Target.Offset(1).Value  "" Then
             If MsgBox("Do you want to overwrite the cell below (containing '" & _
                 Target.Offset(1) & "?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
                 Target.Resize(2).Merge
            End If
        Else
            Target.Resize(2).Merge
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Note: The code needs to go in the target sheet, not a new module, as it is an Event procedure:

[image: code placement]

Comment: sorry - i forgot to mention that i found a solution to check the value under the cell, but thanks very much. It works as i intended

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark the answer as solved then so the question gets closed!